# Trying to send Data from API A to API B along with request body, API B is throwing error saying can't find req.body

Tags: node.js, axios, multipartform-data, multipart

I have to upload photos and videos to a third party api, I am trying to send request using axios.

my code is as following,

```
const file_media = await fs.createReadStream(fileName); //fileName is valid file_path/fileName.ext
const metadata = { fileName: file.fileName, fileExt: file.fileExt };  // I have to send this data to third party api in request body

const request_config = {
    headers: {
        "Authorization": admin_token_ccr,
        "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data",
    },
    data: {
        file: file_media,
        metadata: JSON.stringify(metadata),
    }
};

const response = await axios.post(process.env.CCR_LOGIN_URL + "/start/multipart", request_config.data, { headers: request_config.headers });
```

third party API is responding as following.

```
{
  error: true,
  errorCode: 4324,
  data: [
    {
      msg: 'File name is required',
      param: 'fileName',
      location: 'body'
    },
    { msg: 'File ext is required', param: 'fileExt', location: 'body' }
  ],
  message: 'Invalid Input'
}
```

I have tried multiple solution as mentioned in threads but none of them seem to work.

I am using nodejs v14 with express.

I tried sending data in multiple ways and unable to send data exactly what api is expecting.

basically this endpoint (where request is being sent) is used to upload file.

I have to send 2 things in request

1. file (it can be any type[mp4, pdf, ppt, xlsx, csv, txt] up to 5gb in size)
2. Json Object which have following two properties, A) fileName, B) fileExt

Comment: `location: 'body'` in the error messages sounds to me as if it was expecting those parameters directly as part of the request body? Do you have any documentation for this endpoint we could look at?

Comment: Yes it is expecting a file and body = { fileName: "anything", fileExt:'.anyExtension'}

No, I do not have such documentation it's an internal code(other team members have created api that will upload data in s3 bucket) in our school project.

Comment: But you are not sending them as body parameters, you are sending a `metadata` parameter. Can't tell you whether that's correct or not, you will have to talk to the people in charge of this API then.

Comment: Sorry I should have been more clear, I tried sending as body backend was always getting body empty so I was trying different ways to send data.
@CBroe

Comment: I even tried sending just body data not attaching file,
just req.body where it is expecting fileName and fileExt